# AlignAssign R addin does not show up after installing

Tags: r, package, add-in

I am trying to install the add in **AlignAssign**, but after installing it does not show up under Addins drop down menu. Does any one have experience with that? I would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by restarting my session...

Hope that helps!